# Accessor for Pivot-Column in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

My database looks like this:

**dishes** (id, image)

**dish_location** (location_id, dish_id, dishcard_sharing)

**locations** (id, name)

The columns *image* and *dishcard_sharing* are both paths like */images/1234/123123.jpg*. For the *dishes.image-column* I just added an accessor to prepend the S3-url. Now I need such an accessor for the *dish_location.dishcard_sharing colunm* too. But where to implement it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;
use App\Models\DishLocationPivot;

class Dish extends Model
{
    public $table_name = 'dishes';

    public function locations() {
        return $this
          ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'dish_location', 'dish_id', 'location_id')
          ->withPivot(['dishcard_sharing']);
    }

    /* Accessors */
    public function getImageAttribute($value) {
        return config('filesystems.store_url_prefix') . $value;
    }

    public function scopeFinalize($query) {

      // Dish Card?
      $query->addSelect('dish_location.dishcard_sharing AS dishcard_sharing');
      return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a regular old function that constructs the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a new class that extends the Pivot:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class DishLocation extends Pivot {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. Maybe you should add the ->using() part to your answer for somebody else, who has the same question ;-)

Comment: Now I can access this value by doing something like this: $dish->pivot->dishcard_sharing... Is it possible to "move" it to $dish->dishcard_sharing? Adding a select ignores the accessor of the Pivot-model... Thank you! :)